# override page PreInit inside Custom server control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, datatemplate

I have custom server control contains templatefield when an out button clicked the field disappear , when can I rebind the control (inside its class) supposed that Control.Page.OnInit+=new EventHandler(rebind()) doesn't do any things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just rebind the control OnLoad() will solve the problem.